# LINQ to XML query with a where clause with attribute("id").value=="1"

Tags: linq-to-xml

I want to add an element into an XML file with the condition:

```
like where attribute("id").value=="1"
```

In this code the `where` clause does not work:

```
string xmlFilePath = MapPath("Employees.xml");
XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Load(xmlFilePath);
try
{
    xmlDoc.Element("employees").Element("employee")
        .Where(employee => employee.Attribute("id").Value == "2").FirstOrDefault())
        .Add(new XElement("city", "welcome"));

    xmlDoc.Save(xmlFilePath);
}
catch (XmlException ex)
{
    //throw new XmlException
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand the question. Can you clarify it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This might work better:

```
XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Load(xmlFilePath);
try
{
    xmlDoc
        // get the employees element
        .Element("employees")
        // get all the employee elements
        .Elements("employee")
        // but filter down to the first one that has id == 2
        .Where(employee => employee.Attribute("id").Value == "2").FirstOrDefault()
        // and add a new city element to it
        .Add(new XElement("city", "welcome"));
    // save the document
    xmlDoc.Save("D:\\x.xml");
}
catch (XmlException ex)
{
    //throw new XmlException
}
```